# SignalR sometimes not calling the client methods

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr

I have a SignalR hub where it is pushing some number increments (and decrements) to Javascript clients in a webpage. ASP.NET MVC page pulls the initial value from the database initially, and then SignalR kicks in. The methods are generally invoked, but some get lost in the way. For example:

- The initial value of `x` is, say, 100000.
- Server increments generally about 100 times in a minute.
- The value of `x` is incremented at the client about 50-60 times, so say `x` becomes 100055.
- When I refresh the page, `x` is pulled from the database, and it's actual value of 100100.

The hub code is extremely simple, and I'm logging when data comes from the server:

```
$(function () {
    var connection = $.connection.adminhub;
    var myToken = "@ViewBag.Code";

    connection.client.increment = function (data) {
        console.log("SignalR: increment " + data);
        var num = parseInt($("#" + data).text());
        $("#" + data).text(num + 1);
    };

    connection.client.decrement = function (data) {
        console.log("SignalR: decrement " + data);
        var num = parseInt($("#" + data).text());
        $("#" + data).text(num - 1);
    };
    console.log("Connecting to SignalR...");
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        console.log("Connected to SignalR.");
        connection.server.registerForIndex(myToken);
    });

});
```

`ViewBag.Code` is a special token written by the server, it works (otherwise it can't receive any data). There is only one place on the server which calls the hub's method:

```
    static IHubContext Instance{
        get
        {
            return GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<AdminHub>();
        }
    }

    public static void Increment(string key)
    {
        Instance.Clients.Group("stats").increment(key);
    }
```

My client(s) is/are registered in the `stats` group. I've tried with different browsers and different OS's, they act all the same. I've checked the lifetime events and there are no connection slowdowns, disconnects, reconnects. I am connected using websockets transport, and my connection to both the Internet and the server is quite stable. Why are my values off by about 50% and how can I correct this behavior?

Comment: Please consider heaven : https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/signalr

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you've shown that would explain this; I suggest trying to create a minimal example to reproduce the issue; maybe your data param isn't always what you're expecting

Comment: @LarsHöppner There are not even parameters. SignalR just RPCs increment or decrement method on the JS client.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I can't login with Facebook, login mechanism is broken.

Comment: in your code sample, you're using the data/key param to select the DOM element, that's what I meant; I tried a simple version of what you're doing with 2 messages per second and it worked as expected (v2.0.3), so I'd say there's some aspect about what you're doing that's not in the question; questions: did you compare the number of log statements to the number of calls you were expecting? does it happen with a single client? SignalR version?

Comment: @LarsHöppner the number of logs are also less than I've expected so it's not a DOM issue.. my SignalR version is 2.0.2, I'll upgrade to 2.0.3 to see if the problem persists. the problem happens with a single client. i'm testing it in an isolated system. it won't be available for public, it's only for an admin panel, and I verify that I'm the only one connected to the panel when trying these. (it should be just fine with more though)

Comment: BTW, the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that retrieving data from signalr is an asynchronous operation. Even though Javascript is single threaded you cant be sure that a picked number is incremented before another request picked the same number from the html element. Maybe extend your log method to see what numbers are actually picked from the HTML Element.

However, 100 increments per minute should be feasable. I recommend to subscribe to the lifetime events and have a look at the connection status. Maybe the connection is slow or needs to reconnect quite often.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#connectionlifetime

Comment: I've subscribed to all events (connect, reconnect, disconnect, connection slow) but everything looks very stable. I am on a good, stable Internet connection, connected to my server using websockets, and my site is also stable. I have no idea why I'm not getting some of the increments.

Comment: Have you also extended the log to see what number is picked? What could be is that a request is picking number 60 from the html element and before it can increment it to 61 another request is coming in and picks number 60, too. What then happens is that the first request increments its number to 61 and writes it back into the html element and the second request increments its number to 61, too, and writes it back to the html element. That would be a situation, where you have "lost" an incrementing request.

Comment: I really doubt it is the issue. I am logging all the requests from server and I haven't seen any consecutive requests coming fast. I have also some other fields which don't increment at all while they should be incrementing.